# how to find if key value pair exists in json object using switch statement

Tags: javascript, json, switch-statement

```
json type :1
var x={
    "address": {
        "county": "abc",
        "state_district": "asd",
        "state": "test",
        "country": "test1",
        "country_code": "test"
    }
 }
Type:2
var x ={ "address": {
            "suburb": "",
            "city_district": "",
            "city": "",
            "county": "",
            "state": "",
            "postcode": "",
            "country": "",
           
        }}
type:3
 var x= {"address": {
            "amenity": "",
            "road": "",
            "town": "",
            "county": "",
            "state_district": "",
            "state": "",
            "postcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "country_code": ""
        }
    }
switch(x.address)
{
    case 'city':
        return x.address.city;
        break;
    case 'village':
        return x.address.village;
        break;    
    default:
        alert('err');}
```

This my JSON content.  `address` property will have some additional key values depending on locality like `city`, `village`, `suburb`, etc.

I need to check if a particular key is present or not using switch statement. Sample JSON with additional property are shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer from Fiouze, you can also do these:

```js
// will return true if the property exists.
'city' in x.address

// will return a value if set or undefined if not.
x.address.city
```

But if you want to stick with the switch case, you can iterate through the properties by doing something like:

```
for (const prop in x.address) {
  switch (prop) {
    case 'city': 
      return x.address.city;
    case 'village':
      return x.address.village;
    default:
      alert('err');
  }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`

```js
    if(x.address.hasOwnProperty('city')){
        return x.address.city
    }else if(x.address.hasOwnProperty('village')){
        return(x.address.village)
    }else{
        alert('err')
    }

See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/hasOwnProperty
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch is meant to evaluate a single value, not several property names of an object.

The following function `fn()` duplicates the intent of your switch block:

```js
const myObject = {
  "address": {
    "amenity": "",
    "road": "",
    "town": "FAKE_TOWN",
    "county": "",
    "state_district": "",
    "state": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "country": "",
    "country_code": ""
  }
};

function fn(obj) {
  const {address} = obj;
  
  // get value of the first property that exists
  // note: `??` is the nullish coalescing operator
  const val =
    address.city ??
    address.village ??
    address.town;

  // duplicate the `default` case behavior
  if (val === undefined) {
    alert('err');
    return undefined;
  }

  return val;
}

console.log(`fn: "${fn(myObject)}"`);
```